# model_dump_json() not working with Union Type

Tags: python

I have a `pydantic` class where it is mimicing a MongoDB document, meaning some fields can either be an id, or a de-referenced full document. I am minimicing this using a union field like so:

```py
from typing import Annotated, Any, Union

from bson import ObjectId
from pydantic_core import core_schema
from pydantic import BaseModel

from pydantic.json_schema import JsonSchemaValue


class ObjectIdPydanticAnnotation:
    @classmethod
    def validate_object_id(cls, v: Any, handler) -> ObjectId:
        if isinstance(v, ObjectId):
            return v

        s = handler(v)
        if ObjectId.is_valid(s):
            return ObjectId(s)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(cls, source_type, _handler) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        assert source_type is ObjectId
        return core_schema.no_info_wrap_validator_function(
            cls.validate_object_id,
            core_schema.str_schema(),
            serialization=core_schema.to_string_ser_schema(),
        )

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_json_schema__(cls, _core_schema, handler) -> JsonSchemaValue:
        return handler(core_schema.str_schema())


class Foo(BaseModel):
    id: Annotated[ObjectId, ObjectIdPydanticAnnotation]
    name: str


class Bar(BaseModel):
    foo: Annotated[ObjectId, ObjectIdPydanticAnnotation] | Foo
```

However when I want to convert this model to JSON, if the type of `foo` is `Foo` then it calls `str` on it, rahter than calling `.model_dump_json()`

```py
d = {
    "foo": "64b7abdecf2160b649ab6085"
}
print(Bar.model_validate(d))

d = {
    "foo": {
        "id": "64b7abdecf2160b649ab6085",
        "name": "test"
    }
}
print(Bar.model_validate(d))
print(Bar.model_validate(d).model_dump_json())
```

This prints:

```
foo=ObjectId('64b7abdecf2160b649ab6085')
foo=Foo(id=ObjectId('64b7abdecf2160b649ab6085'), name='test')
{"foo":"id=ObjectId('64b7abdecf2160b649ab6085') name='test'"}
```

Where I would expect the last line to look like:

```
{"foo": {"id": "64b7abdecf2160b649ab6085", name: "test"}}
```

How can I fix this?